# How to perform average function with JOOQ when using timeBucketGapfill()

Tags: java, time-series, jooq, timescaledb

I have a table which represents time series data and I want to write a simple JOOQ query which will calculate the average value; however, the data is not perfect, meaning that there are multiple intervals in which I don't have any value. I want to resolve this problem using the `timeBucketGapfill`, so to fill the gaps with last observed value.
I tried in multiple ways to write this query but I couldn't fix the following error:

```
ERROR: no top level time_bucket_gapfill in group by clause; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no top level time_bucket_gapfill in group by clause
```

And the code:

```
public static final String TIME = "time";
public static final String VALUE = "value";

OffsetDateTime start = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-01-01T00:00:00Z");
OffsetDateTime end = OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-12-31T23:00:00Z");

Field<OffsetDateTime> timeField = createTimeBucketGapfill();

dsl.select(timeField, DSL.avg(TIME_SERIES.VALUE).as(VALUE))
          .from(TIME_SERIES)
          .where(TIME_SERIES.TIME.between(start, end))
          .and(TIME.SERIES.ID.eq(id))
          .groupBy(timeField)
          .fetch();

 private Field<OffsetDateTime> createTimeBucketGapfill() {
        TimeBucketGapfill6 timeBucketGapfill = new TimeBucketGapfill6();
        timeBucketGapfill.setBucketWidth(YearToSecond.valueOf(Duration.between(start, end)));
        timeBucketGapfill.setTs(TIME_SERIES.TIME);
        return timeBucketGapfill.asField(TIME);
    }
```

I decided to set the `start` and the `end`in the `where` clause and not in the `timeBucket` because according to timescaleDB documentation, it is more performant. However, as expected, even if I set them in the `timeBucket`, I get the same error.

Comment: It looks like your groupby doesn't include your `timeField` I think that it might need to include that?

Comment: it is actually included, look again at the code (it was a copy-paste error)

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like ([in your debug log output](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/logging/))?

Comment: `jOOQ; SQL [select "public"."time_bucket_gapfill"("bucket_width" := cast(? as interval), "ts" := cast("public"."series_points_float"."time" as timestamp(6) with time zone)) as "time", avg("public"."series_points_float"."value") as "value" from "public"."series_points_float" where ("public"."series_points_float"."time" between cast(? as timestamp(6) with time zone) and cast(? as timestamp(6) with time zone) and "public"."series_points_float"."series" = ?) group by "time"];`

Comment: Hm, and that works if you run it in timescaledb directly?

Comment: The group by is appearing as "time", and it's probably interpreting that incorrectly. you can't get it to actually generate the time_bucket_gapfill call again? because you also have a column in the table called "time" so it's probably trying to group by the column in the table, not the alias for the expression. If you can get it to instead do something like `GROUP BY 1`, that would be fine as well. Anyway, first thing I'd try is change `public static final String TIME = "time";` to use a different value for `"time"`...

Comment: @LukasEder, no I get the same error

Comment: @davidk, I changed the alias name, as you suggested and I ge other error:  
`[22023] ERROR: invalid time_bucket_gapfill argument: ts needs to refer to a single column if no start or finish is supplied Hint: Specify start and finish as arguments or in the WHERE clause.`. 
But the start and end are specified, as you see

Comment: this is how the SQL looks like:
`select "public"."time_bucket_gapfill"("bucket_width" := cast('+1-0 +17:00:00.000000000' as interval), "ts" := cast("public"."series_points_float"."time" as timestamp(6) with time zone) as "timeInterval", avg("public"."series_points_float"."value") as "value" from "public"."series_points_float" where ("public"."series_points_float"."time" between timestamp with time zone '2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00' and timestamp with time zone '2020-12-31 23:00:00+00:00' and "public"."series_points_float"."series" = 3) group by "timeInterval"`

Comment: why are you casting the time column? I think you should be able to do : `select "public"."time_bucket_gapfill"("bucket_width" := cast('+1-0 +17:00:00.000000000' as interval), "ts" := "public"."series_points_float"."time") as "timeInterval", avg("public"."series_points_float"."value") as "value" from "public"."series_points_float" where ("public"."series_points_float"."time" between timestamp with time zone '2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00' and timestamp with time zone '2020-12-31 23:00:00+00:00' and "public"."series_points_float"."series" = 3) group by 1`